# WOPI Editing document error

Tags: ms-wopi

I'm successfully able to view the word documents using WOPI.
Now, I'm trying to edit the document using WOPI and all wopi tests related to `Locking` as passing.
[image]

But when I try to edit the docx file and request the WOPI client I get this error:

[image]

I see the requests to my server for LOCK and UNLOCK. Not sure what exactly happened to fail and not requesting the PUTFILE.

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the log, you are getting `409 Conflict` during the second request.

You must provide a correct `X-WOPI-Lock` header to unlock the file, otherwise you'll get the `409` which means "Lock mismatch/locked by another interface".

See the [documentation](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/Unlock.html#unlock).

Comment: Works likes charm!! Saved my day! Thanks @rocky.